# Crashlytics Icon doesn't show up in firebase console

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I've implemented the new firebase crashlytics in my application but for some reason I don't see a crashlytics tab anywhere, just a tab for crash reporting. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the Firebase console tab in your browser?  My console tab had been open in my browser for days and didn't update to show Crashlytics until I closed and reopened it.

Comment: @BobSnyder Yes, I've already tried that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you're referring to this:

[image]

**7th November 2017:**

(As I write this answer) Crashlytics is still in beta and is slowly rolling out for users. You should get it as soon as possible. Otherwise there is an [opt-in link](https://console.firebase.google.com/optin/devsummit).

**Note** If you're using multiple Google accounts, make sure you have the correct account selected within the Firebase Console.

Comment: Thank you, I just got the new layout! But Crashlytics still isn't showing... I think I just have to wait, but I can't access my crashes and one user is complaining in a review on the app store. Isn't there a way to force it to show up?

Comment: And the user has the version of the app with Crashlytics already implemented in Firebase? Or do you have it in Fabric?

Comment: Yes, I've set it up with the official Firebase docs, and it is already in production...

Comment: Maybe it just needs some time to link and display. I know it's tough when your users are complaining, but I don't think there's much we can do now...

Comment: Yeah, it's very though but you are right? If I would contact Firebase's support team, would that make a difference?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Make sure you've opted in as @Albert-Jan mentioned.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Well, I've already opted-in and got the new black layout on the left, all the new analytics features of firebase show up but for some reason only crashlytics not. (Ps. Michal answered my question ;) )

Ps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCbRqk-Mzm4ZdDTRRMB8IWiIcP4r_deJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Albert-Jan Yea, Michal did answer it, but the opt-in should get you past the slow roll out. Are you using multiple accounts in Firebase?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I didn't activate it with my other account, I didn't came up with this because the new layout had already showed up, thank you so much! You saved me haha